# Error for storing paragraph data in MYSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I want to store text editor content in MYSQL. That content may be exceed 10 pages. Now i set the field data type as text. It returns error message..

```
ERROR :   Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

How can i solve this issue ..  Please help me to do this..

My table Structure is :

```
fldid      int not null auto_increment unique
fldhead    varchar(400)
fldcontent Text
```

and content have more than 6 word pages..

Comment: Please show the Table schema and insert statement code that you are using.

Comment: most likely you type your ALTER command (you said you change to text datatype?) and add NOT NULL to it. Thats why the update is not working. Leave it for once, update all rows that have NULL in the column with a default ( ' ' ) and then apply the NOT NULL with another alter statement.

Comment: Try applying MySqlHelper.EscapeString() to your text before inserting.

Comment: I was truncate the table and insert the new data.The same error displayed..

Comment: @astander Please see my post again

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no issue with the content you are trying to insert. Also it appears that you are using InnoDB and have specified relations with other tables.

Prima facia, the record you are trying to insert is some how related to other tables and the restrictions it poses are not fulfilled and hence it is denying to insert the record.

If you could post here the relationships with other table, it would be helpful.